# how to merge ajax request with ajax response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

[image: What i want ?]

Actually I am looking for something like above picture.

I was trying to add ajax request with ajax response,How ever i have failed with that one please help me out.

Source code:

```
$(function () {
var availableTags = [

    "gmail.com", "hotmail.com", "outlook.com", 


];

function customFilter(array, terms) {
    arrayOfTerms = terms.split("@");
    var term = $.map(arrayOfTerms, function (tm) {
         return $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(tm);
    }).join('|');
   var matcher = new RegExp("\\b" + term, "i");
    return $.grep(array, function (value) {
       return matcher.test(value.label || value.value || value);
    });
};

$("#tags").autocomplete({



    multiple: true,
    mustMatch: false


    ,source: function (request, response) {

        // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
        response(customFilter(
        availableTags, request.term));
    },
});


          });
```

I have got this one..

[image]

Comment: Your source parameter is repeated in your autocomplete call.   I don't believe that's valid, at least I cannot find an example where anyone has done that.

Comment: it's valid in that it won't cause an error, however only the second one will be used.

Comment: @KevinB ya u are right

Comment: I have a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L2GFL/) maybe that helps.

Comment: @Wilmer Thanks a lot.Post think  as a answer.will rate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following overrides the source array to prepend the request term:

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        if( request.term.indexOf("@") == -1 ){//char "@" not in request

            var arr = $.map(availableTags, function (tag, i) {
                return (request.term + "@" + tag);
            });

            response(arr);
        }
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L2GFL/)

Comment: @wilmers how ever it's coming n number of times when user press space button after first time.ex: myexample@gmail.com@gmail.com.

Comment: I updated the answer to prevent duplicate responses I check for "@" in the request.